# retrieve value of query string

Tags: asp-classic, query-string

I want to retrieve the value through query string and then use this value to pass in the url as offset of the page in asp classic.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use request("item") but that will provide you from the querystring or from a form posting

request.querystring("item) is more specific.

http://www.asp101.com/articles/pauld/request/default.asp

I can't make sense of the second half of your question.

Answer (score 1):

use to get values from querystring.

```
    Request.QueryString("your querystring name");
```